# Passing properties to Polymer 1.0 from Angular 2

Tags: angular, polymer

I'm trying to use Polymer in an Angular 2 component. When I pass static values to Polymer they appear, but when I try to have Angular 2 bind a variable to the Polymer component it doesn't come through. Polymer gets the default value and runs fine, but can't see the value from Angular.

A Plunker of this behavior is here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/FU5cWuuc7vIz8lvtPwuC?p=preview

From what I've read, I should be able to bind the Angular 2 value with this syntax:

```
<polymer-component [(polymer-property)]="angular2Varialbe"></polymer-component>
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong, but any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angular documentation states:

> "In the world of Angular 2, the only role of attributes is to
>   initialize element and directive state. When we data bind, we're
>   dealing exclusively with element and directive **properties** and events.
>   Attributes effectively disappear."

So, the correct way to get the binding to work is to write `[(userName)]` and not `[(user-name)]`.

Even though this seems to "work", it only does from Angular to Polymer, not the other way around. Making angular blind to changes on the webcomponent.

I've made an example using your code with two way data binding using methods described on the documentation (I hope they will make the integration easier, helping to reduce the boilerplate):

```
<hello-name [userName]="userName" (user-name-changed)="userName=$event.target.userName" id="hero"></hello-name>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/dwd1x3o6RgyOxwNjyIBx?p=preview

In the example, I've added a button which changes the webcomponent property, and you can verify how it updates the angular model, also, if you change the id `"hero"`:

```
let element = document.getElementById("hero");
```

to:

```
let element = document.getElementById("hero0");
```

You can verify how the boilerplate is needed. In this case the node doesn't have the `(user-name-changed)="userName=$event.target.userName"` just `[(userName)]="userName"`, when you update the property of the web component through javascript, the angular context is never updated.

Comment: This is exactly the right solution, and your plunker did a great job of illustrating the one and two way binding scenarios! Thank you for the help!