# How can I convert angular 2 components to webcomponents?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 2 and built a few components. Is there a way to convert those components to webcomponents ? Is there a way to transpile this first and then made available in other (nonangular) web applications for reuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use web components in Angular2 (with some limitations) but there is no way to transpile or convert it automatically in any way.

Comment: So Polymer would be suitable to create web components which I can use in angular 2 and non angular sites?

Comment: There are a few issues but it's working and Angular will improve interoperability with Polymer and other custom elements. See also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356888/polymer-paper-menu-with-angular2, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456554/passing-properties-to-polymer-1-0-from-angular-2, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779175/polymer-elements-within-angular-2-component/34782260#34782260, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864501/using-paper-datatable-in-angular2/36864636#36864636

Comment: is this answer still true after angular2 final release? We cannot convert an angular2 app to a webcomponent and import it into another web application?

Comment: No, such plans were dropped. It doesn't look like it's planned for later. That might change of course.